# Is the $\sigma$-algebra of measurable sets a maximal family to which the lenght can be extended without losing its properties?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I appologize if the question in the title of the post is not clear. What I mean is this:

Can we prove that starting with the semi-algebra of intervals and the lenght function defined on it and proceeding by Caratheodory's method the $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{M}$ obtained of measurables sets is maximal in the sense that if we enlarge this family by adding a non-measurable set then the outer measure restricted to this new family $\mathcal{M}'$ loses the property of being $\sigma$-additive or the propery of being invariant under translations?

Let $\mathcal{M}'$ be a family containing $\mathcal{M}$ and such that there exist $M \in \mathcal{M}'$ and $X \subset \mathbb{R}$ satisfying
$$m^*(X)<m^*(X\cap M) + m^*(X\cap M^c)$$ where $m^*$ is Lebesgue' outer measure.

I don't see how this can contradict $m^*$ being traslational invariant and $\sigma$-additive on $\mathcal{M}'$

Answer (score 0):

You don't lose translation invariance, since [$m^*$ is translation invariant](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/900434/22857).

But you immediately lose the $\sigma$-additivity: for your $M$ and $X$, 
$$
m^*((M\cap X)\cup(M^c\cap X))<m^*(M\cap X)+m^*(M^c\cap X),
$$
so $m^*$ is not even additive in your enlarged $\sigma$-algebra.

In summary, $\mathcal M(\mathbb R)$ is maximal with respect to $\sigma$-additivity. It isn't with respect to translation invariance.

Comment: But it is not assumed $X \in \mathcal{M}'$ so $M\cap X$ and $M^c \cap X$ doesn't need to be in $\mathcal{M}'$ either. In that case that inequality doesn't seem to prove $m^*$ is not additive in $\mathcal{M}'$

Comment: I'm not even sure if $M^c \in \mathcal{M}'$ since I'm not assuming this enlarged family is a $\sigma-$algebra

Comment: Why do you say that $\mathcal M(\mathbb R)$ is maximal with respect to $\sigma$-additivity? I seem to recall an exercise in Halmos to the effect that a $\sigma$-finite measure on a $\sigma$-ring $S$ can always be extended to a measure on the $\sigma$-ring generated by $S$ and a finite number of additional sets.