# Show that Lebesgue measure is translation-invariant.

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $A \subset \mathbb{R^n}$ and $x \in \mathbb{R^n}$ and $A + x= :\{u: u - x \in A\}$. If $A$ is measurable, then $A + x$ is also measurable and $\mu(A) = \mu(A+x)$. This means that the Lebesgue measure is translation-invariant.

How can I start the proof? Any help is appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: How did you define Lebesgue measure in the first place? If it's the restriction of the Lebesgue outer measure to the measurable sets, then you can pretty much just expand the definition of the Lebesgue outer measure (convert a cover of $A$ into a cover of $A+x$ by just translating it), and everything will work out.

Comment: this is almost immediate from the Lebesgue outer measure

Comment: There are quite a few  [elementary proofs of this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/542975/how-to-prove-that-lebesgue-outer-measure-is-translation-invariant) but one way to avoid the proof from scratch is to observe that $E\mapsto x+E$ defines a measure $\nu$ on the algebra $\mathscr A$ of half-open cubes in $\mathbb R^n$, that agrees with the Lebesgue measure on $\mathscr A$, hence on all of $\mathscr B(\mathbb R^n)$. The result now follows because it also is $0$ on the Lebesgue -null sets.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to prove that Lebesgue outer measure is translation invariant?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/542975/how-to-prove-that-lebesgue-outer-measure-is-translation-invariant)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a brief proof of the one dimensional case.

**Theorem:** If $A \subset \Bbb{R}$ is Lebesgue measurable, then for every $x \in \Bbb{R}$, $m(A)=m(A+x)$.

**Proof:**

If $A \subset \Bbb{R}$ is Lebesgue measurable, then define its measure to be

$$m(A):=\inf \{\sum_n l((a_n,b_n]): A \subset \bigcup_n (a_n,b_n], l((a_n,b_n])=b_n-a_n\}.$$

So we have that $A \subset \cup_n (a_n,b_n]$, then for any $x \in \Bbb{R}$,

$$A+x \subset \cup_n(a_n+x,b_n+x].$$

And since

\begin{align}
l((a_n+x,b_n+x])&=(b_n+x)-(a_n+x)\\
&= b_n - a_n\\
&= l((a_n,b_n])
\end{align}
Holds for every $n$, their infimums agree thus $m(A)=m(A+x)$. $\blacksquare$

***Added:*** I am using the definition of Lebesgue measure from Bass, Real Analysis for Graduate Students. However this works if we cover $A$ by any countable union of intervals.