# Proof of translation and linear transformation invariance of R_k

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, outer-measure

Let A be a Lebesgue measurable set. Suppose that $f$ and $g_r$ are respectively the translation and linear tansformation with ratio $r$ on $\mathbb{R}_k$.
Prove that $f(A)$ and $g_r(A)$ are Lebesgue measurable sets and

$m_k(f(A))=m_k(A)$

$m_k(g_r(A))=m_k(A).r$

$m_k(x+A)=m_k(A)$

$m_k(rA)=\vert r \vert .m_k(A)(r \neq 0)$

I start from scratch and what the idea of the begining of the proof ? Thank you

Comment: Welcome to MSE. You should indicate what you have done so far, where you are stuck, etc., otherwise your post can be downvoted and eventually closed.

Comment: Thank you for reminding me, but I have no idea to do this exercise. Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: For translation invariance, see [Show that Lebesgue measure is translation-invariant](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3067692/show-that-lebesgue-measure-is-translation-invariant?rq=1), and references contained there.

Comment: I have read this before but it seems to consider translation invariance, how about homothetic transformation invariance ? how to prove that image of homothetic tranformation is a Lebesgue measurable set ?